# Memory Management example

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Here is some of the code from one of my classes, I was wondering am I handling the memory right or am I leaking anywhere?

```
@implementation CardViewController
@synthesize playerImage;
@synthesize cardLabel;
@synthesize card;
@synthesize frontView;
@synthesize backView;
@synthesize nameLabel;
@synthesize infoLabel;
@synthesize delegate;

-(void) initialiseButtons 
{
NSLog(@"initialiseButtons  %d",totalButtons);
int ypos = playerImage.frame.origin.y + playerImage.frame.size.height + 42;
for(int i=0; i<totalButtons; i++) 
{       
    StatView *sv = [[StatView alloc] initWithYPos:ypos];
    sv.tag = 100 + i;
    [sv.overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(statTapped:)    
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    sv.overlayButton.tag = 10 + i;
    [self.frontView addSubview:sv];
    ypos += 26;
}
}

-(IBAction) statTapped:(id) sender 
{

UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
int tag = tappedButton.tag;
if(delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cardTapped:)]) {
    [delegate cardTapped:tag-10];
}
 }

-(void) viewDidLoad 
{
NSLog(@" viewDidLoad CVC");
[self initialiseButtons];

metaData = [[NSArray alloc]     
      initWithObjects:@"Height",@"Weight",@"Games",@"Attack",@"Defense", nil];
 }

-(void) setCard:(Card *)newCard 
{
NSLog(@"setCard");
[card release];
card = [newCard retain];
[self updateUI];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
[card autorelease];
[metaData autorelease];
 [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Where should I release StatView *sv = [[StatView alloc] initWithYPos:ypos];
If i released it every loop wouldnt that cause problems?
Besides that do I handle the rest of the memory ok?

Thanks
-Code

Comment: Are there tags I can use in posts so that the snippets of code i post are displayed nicely?

Comment: yes - the directions were there where you entered your question.  Use four spaces or the 101010 button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Release the new `StatView` after this line

   `[self.frontView addSubview:sv];`

   `[sv release]; // frontView retains sv`
2. Release all properties declared as `retain` or `copy` in `dealloc`. Candidate properties: playerImage, cardLabel etc. Send a `release` message, not `autorelease`

   `\\[card autorelease];`

   `[card release];`
3. In `viewDidUnload` release all properties that are declared as `IBOutlet` and set the variable to `nil`

   `[frontView release], frontView = nil;`

Comment: What do you mean by  Candidate properties: ?

Comment: Properties that I am guessing are retained.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should release that StatView at the end of each loop iteration, when you've inserted it into the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the analyzer built into XCode as it is very good at finding these type of memory leaks. Have a [look](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should release it as soon as you've added it to the view hierarchy (by sending `addSubview:` with the newly-allocated view as an argument). This is because UIView objects retain their subviews.

One other problem I notice: your setCard method should first check whether the new and old cards are identical, and do nothing in that case. Otherwise, you may release your existing card, then try to retain it again, only to find that it has been dealloced.